# Relocation of messages is broken on chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

Cannot relocate messages in chat since yesterday.

[image]

More specifically `POST` to `http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/minilist` returns a 302.

Response headers :

```
Age:0
Cache-Control:private
Content-Length:153
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 16 Jun 2011 09:12:22 GMT
Location:/error?aspxerrorpath=/rooms/minilist
Via:1.1 localhost.localdomain
```

There is nothing useful in the error request to show you.

How else will I move noise and spam to the bin!

**Bonus points:**

What's the ajax call I should manually make to relocate messages? Only the listing of rooms to relocate to is broken.

Comment: I can reproduce the error on chat.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix should be going out now. An unanticipated side-effect of a performance tweak.

Comment: The turn around on report to fixed is impressive. Confirmed that my issue is gone

Comment: @Ryanos we aim to please